# why can't numpy compute long objects?

Tags: python, numpy, long-integer

Say I have a variable which is assigned the type 'long'

```
x = 40*2*10**30
```

If I then attempt to take the log of this variable using numpy (imported as np):

```
np.log10(x)
```

I am faced with an attribute error:

> 'long' object has no attribute 'log10'.

To get around this I can make the variable a float and it works just fine or use the 'math' package:

```
math.log10(x)
np.log10(float(x))
```

My question is: how does math.log10 and np.log10 differ and why is np not set up to handle 'long' types?

Comment: The variable is not really a `long` object, it is a Python's BigInt. You can see this by trying to convert it to a `long` as `np.int64(x)` which will throw you an overflow error. Conversion to float solves this problem, as you already discovered.

Comment: @jonrsharpe He didn't name a long variable as np. I also thought that, but weirdly enough, if you try the code it prompts that error. I guess numpy's error are a bit ofuscated.

Comment: Huh, that's a profoundly unhelpful error message!

Comment: @jonrsharpe it looks like since numpy can't convert the long to numpy type it falls back to treating it's dtype as object. Meaning numpy can still do things like `np.add(2**64, 1)` and compute the correct result. That is, if `long` defined `log10` then numpy would have been able to produce a result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that numpy is written in C and it does not have a data type that can handle a number as large as the regular python int class. If you go here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html  it explains the different data types allowed in numpy. Take special note of the int64 dtype, the largest numbers allowed in that type are much smaller than the integer number that you have input. However float64 (which is equivalent to double in C) can handle up to an 11 bit exponent, which is why when you convert to float there is no overflow error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does anyone know of what the differences are between the different maths packages are then?

Comment: @LRP your comment is not a comment but a question. if you wish to ask a question please ask a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask